# SQL Server : create batch of Employees and prevent one emp going to multiple batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, multithreading, batch-processing

My table contains data about `Employee`. However it is a temporary table and `EmployeeID` here isn't the primary key. The table may contain a given `EmployeeID` multiple times.

Now, I have to select batch of records of `batchSize`, let's consider 200 for now. I'll send these batches to multiple threads.

I have written this query:

```
WITH SingleBatch AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmployeeId) AS RowNumber
    FROM 
        TemperoryTable
)
SELECT *
FROM SingleBatch
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 200;
```

the result might be:

```
  EmployeeID  EffectiveDate
1   123        01/01/2016
2   541        01/01/2016
------------------------
------------------------
200 978       18/06/2015
```

for one batch.
This works fine and row numbers change with thread number.

Now suppose, second batch starts with EmployeeId `978`. Then this employee will be in first batch as well as second batch. That is, same employee is being sent to multiple threads and may possibly cause conflict.
Although the scenario is very rare, I must avoid this.

What could be the possible solution here?

Comment: Providing the expected result as sample data would be much easier for understanding than explaining the expected result in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't get it before, you wish same empolyee can be gotten together? but the total return rows count possible is not fix number.  May this is helpful for you.

```
    ;WITH t(RowNumber,EmployeeId,other)AS
    (
        SELECT 1,'a','1' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,'a','12' UNION ALL
       SELECT 3,'a','13' UNION ALL
       SELECT 4,'b','21' UNION ALL
       SELECT 5,'d','41' UNION ALL
       SELECT 6,'c','31' UNION ALL
       SELECT 7,'c','32' 

    )
    SELECT *,DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY EmployeeId) AS FilterID,RANK()OVER(ORDER BY EmployeeId) RowsCount FROM t
```

```
RowNumber   EmployeeId other FilterID             RowsCount
----------- ---------- ----- -------------------- --------------------
2           a          12    1                    1
3           a          13    1                    1
1           a          1     1                    1
4           b          21    2                    4
6           c          31    3                    5
7           c          32    3                    5
5           d          41    4                    7
```

Same employeeid has same FilterID, and the RowsCount to control return rows count.
You should get data by RowsCount but rownumber.

For example:
Actual return 6 lines when the RowsCount between 1 and 5.
because the employeeID c have two lines.

Comment: Wonderful.. this seems like will solve my issue. I'll try and if it does, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Between mean RowNumber>=1 and RowNumber<=200
So next batch should be

```
RowNumber BETWEEN 201 AND 400
```

also you can change where clause to

```
RowNumber>=1 and  RowNumber <200  (1-199)
RowNumber>=200 and  RowNumber <400 (200-399)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this isn't solving the problem as there might be more than 2 records of one employee. It could be 3, 4, 5 or more. If 200th employee is John, I want to take all records of John in same thread/batch